# An object reference is required for the non-static field method or property/field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property

Tags: multithreading, winforms, static, field, non-static

I was making a program and I stumbled across this two-in-one problem, where the first problem leads to the other. I have not yet found a question where someone had both problems leading into eachother. I'm still learing, and have learned a lot from other problems I had, but I can't find a solution to this problem.

It has to do with threading. I want to make a thread, that can place something in a rich textbox every second or so, while I can still press buttons to start and stop it. But to make a function that a thread can run, I need to make the function static. Otherwise I'll get the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property". But when a function is static, it cannot acces any of the created items, like richTextBox1. Because if I try to change it's text, I get the error "Error    1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". And if I fix this by removing static, the thread will not work.

I made a demo program that is smaller than the full one, but has the same problem. Button1 is the button to start the thread, Button2 is the one to stop it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace threading_non_static_problem_demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(demofunc));
        int checkthr = 0; //int to check if the thread has been running before (I like to do things like this)
        int ifthrrun = 0; //int to check if the thread is running
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button2.Enabled = false; // so you can't click the "stop" button if nothing is running
        }
        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        static void demofunc()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "text added"; // <-- here's the problem
                MessageBox.Show("tried to add text"); // you can use this messagebox to check if the thread is working correctly
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkthr == 0) // check if the thread has run before, 0 is no, 1 is yes, and then start or resume it
            {
                thr.Start();
                ifthrrun = 1;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (checkthr == 1)
            {
                thr.Resume();
                ifthrrun = 1;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thr.Suspend();
            checkthr = 1;
            ifthrrun = 0;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) // if the program is closing, check the thread's state and act accordingly
        {
            if (ifthrrun == 0)
            {
                if (checkthr == 1)
                {
                    thr.Resume();
                    thr.Abort();
                }
                else if (checkthr == 0)
                {
                }
            }
            else if (ifthrrun == 1)
            {
                thr.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use this code just creat a forms application, add two buttons, and a rich text box, it should work.

Thank you in advance for you answers.

Comment: Don't use a thread, use a timer. It will solve both problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But to make a function that a thread can run, I need to make the
>   function static.

Get rid of the `static` declarations and move initialization of your "thr" variable to the constructor like this:

```
    Thread thr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button2.Enabled = false; // so you can't click the "stop" button if nothing is running
        thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(demofunc));
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    }

    private void demofunc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "text added"; // <-- problem "solved" by disabling Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls
        }
    }
```

But **ignore the above "fix"** because using Suspend()/Resume() is not recommended.

See [Pausing and Resuming Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tttdef8x(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Important
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Thread.Suspend and
>   Thread.Resume methods are marked obsolete and will be removed in a
>   future release.
>
> The Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume methods are not
>   generally useful for applications and should not be confused with
>   synchronization mechanisms. Because Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume
>   do not rely on the cooperation of the thread being controlled, they
>   are highly intrusive and can result in serious application problems
>   like deadlocks (for example, if you suspend a thread that holds a
>   resource that another thread will need).

One way to be able to pause/resume your loop would be to use a [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
    Thread thr;
    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button2.Enabled = false; // so you can't click the "stop" button if nothing is running
        thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(demofunc));
    }

    private void demofunc()
    {
        while (!this.IsDisposed && !this.Disposing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (!this.IsDisposed && !this.Disposing)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {

                    richTextBox1.AppendText("text added");

                });
            }
            mre.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        mre.Set();
        if (!thr.IsAlive)
        {
            thr.Start();
        }
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        button2.Enabled = false;
        mre.Reset();
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) // if the program is closing, check the thread's state and act accordingly
    {
        mre.Set(); // make sure the loop continues so it can drop out
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. Also thanks for letting me know about the suspend and resume thing, I'll keep it in mind.